# How do i enable SSMS to automatically refresh schema changes

Tags: c#, sql-server, intellisense

I have a table where im committing data via a Stored Procedure. I have added two additional columns to the table.When i attempt to do a query on the table from application code im get "Error Invalid column name 'SADC' " but when i attempt the same  in SSMS it returns data correctly. The additional columns are populated using functions and as such are not included in the stored procedure.I understand the issue relates to refreshing the SSMS Intellisense Cache. I have attempted the following but to no avail :
1.Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Transact-SQL -> General. I checked IntelliSense, and found it was enabled already
2.Tools -> Query -> IntelliSense. I have it selected already.
3. Maximum script size is set to "Unlimited" under menu option Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Transact-SQL -> General -> IntelliSense. I have done so.
4.CTRL + Shift + R

The only option i have left is Refreshing Intellisense Cache from the Edit menu. When i click on Edit menu IntelliSense does not appear. I have tried adding the command to the menu in Tools>>Custmize>>Commands but it still not refreshing.

In my code i have :

```
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeNumber FROM EmployeeInfo WHERE Active=" + Convert.ToInt32(Helpers.parameters.active) + " AND Source=" + Convert.ToString(Helpers.parameters.zimra) + "", conn);

            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

The table has a new column Source which is contained in the above query. Any suggestions on how i can refresh the table schema? How can i enable the IntelliSense to automatically appear on Edit menu.

Comment: Even when the intellisense cache is not updated (and the editor shows "errors" for the new fields), the queries will still succeed using those new fields. Editor and intellisense behavior is independent from actual table structure implementation and query execution in that regard. If your application gets an actual error message, it really cannot find the new fields. Are you sure your application is connecting to the same database as your SSMS??

Comment: SSMS IntelliSense is notoriously flaky.  So flaky that there are several commercial products dedicated to fixing *just* the IntelliSense .

Comment: You havent selected any schema to EmployeeInfo - So are you not sure that you dont have 2 tables with EmployeeInfo name? But just in 2 differenent schemas? dbo and emp maybe? As far as i know it searches for dbo schema by default.

Comment: Use parameters. The string interpolation you're using here is subject to SQL injection, and can also easily produce invalid queries when values need to be escaped. Your issues with SSMS and IntelliSense look like complete red herrings to me -- IntelliSense will not affect if queries run successfully or not, on *any* client; all it affects is whether SSMS shows red squigglies and offers autocomplete, neither of which are needed to actually run queries.

Comment: Are you also totally sure SSMS is connected to the same database as your code?  I can't count the number of times I've accidentally connected to a dev / test database, when the code is actually connecting to the other.

Comment: @BradleyUffner ... I do not have any errors on the new columns in SSMS. I have only one instance for the EmployeeInfo table and yes my code is connecting to the same db as SSMS.

Comment: If you evaluated (via the debugger) the query string you generated (and assigned to cmd) you would immediately see the problem with your logic. Parameterize your query and you will solve that problem and many others.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have an undelimited string value in your query.

Try

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeNumber FROM EmployeeInfo WHERE Active=" + Convert.ToInt32(Helpers.parameters.active) + " AND Source='" + Convert.ToString(Helpers.parameters.zimra) + "'", conn);
```

I'm guessing that `Convert.ToString(Helpers.parameters.zimra)` = SADC which undelimited is being interpreted as a column name.